# Separar uma string em C#

Tags: c#

Estou a trabalhar com C# e quero saber , por favor, como faço para separar o conteúdo de um ficheiro q contém a seguinte informação:

Existem **30** calorias em **Abóbora** **(1 chávena)**.
Existem **83** calorias em **Abóbora (sem Sal, Enlatado)** **(1 chávena)**.

Existem **67** calorias em **Mistura de Vegetais (Milho, Feijão Verde, Ervilhas,Cenouras) (sem Sal, Enlatado)** **(1 chávena)**. "

Quero obter os textos a negrito para serem passados para uma variável.

EX: Da linha três do ficheiro quero que as minhas variáveis tenham os valores lá contidos:

```
int calorias = 67; 
string nomeVegetal = "Mistura de Vegetais (Milho, Feijão Verde, Ervilhas,Cenouras) (sem Sal, Enlatado)";
string quantidade = (1 chávena);
```

Nota: Já li o ficheiro e separei por linha, mas em cada linha não estou a conseguir separar de forma a obter o que eu quero.

Comment: Você precisa obter o número (que precede a palavra **calorias**) também?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testa este código.

```
        var texto = "Existem 67 calorias em Mistura de Vegetais (Milho, Feijão Verde, Ervilhas,Cenouras) (sem Sal, Enlatado) (1 chávena).";
        var texto1 = texto.Replace("Existem ", "").Replace(" calorias em ","|");
        var resultado = texto1.Split('|');


        var asdf1 = resultado[1].ToArray();
        var ultimoParenteses = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < asdf1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (asdf1[i].Equals('('))
            {
                ultimoParenteses = i;
            }
        }

        var calorias = resultado[0];
        var nomeVegetal = resultado[1].Substring(0, ultimoParenteses);
        var quantidade = resultado[1].Substring(ultimoParenteses, resultado[1].Length - ultimoParenteses);
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que assim você consiga resolver teu problema partindo do principio que você tem a linha como descrito.

```
var linha = "Existem 30 calorias em Abóbora (1 chávena).";
var palavras = linha.split(" ");
int calorias = int32.parse(palavras[1]);
string nomeVegetal = "";
for(int i = 4; i > calorias.lenght -1; i++){
    nomeVegetal += calorias[i] + " ";
} 
string quantidade = palavras[palavras.lenght-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro separe por linhas, e depois por strings fixas.

No seu caso, os valores numéricos estão na *segunda posição* se utilizarmos um espaço em branco como critério de separação, e o nome na segunda posição se separarmos por `"calorias em "`.

[Versão funcional no .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W1IM2Q).

O seu resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var src = @"Existem 30 calorias em Abóbora (1 chávena).
Existem 83 calorias em Abóbora (sem Sal, Enlatado) (1 chávena).
Existem 67 calorias em Mistura de Vegetais (Milho, Feijão Verde, Ervilhas,Cenouras) (sem Sal, Enlatado) (1 chávena).";


        var linhas = src.Split((char)10).ToList(); // Transforma a string em um 
                                                   // array com 3 linhas.


        for (int i = 0; i < linhas.Count(); i++)
        {
            var qt = linhas[i].Split(' ')[1];
            var nm = linhas[i].Split(new string[] { "calorias em " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            Console.WriteLine(qt + ":" + nm);   
        }
    }
}
```